# Why is Google AppMaker is not allowing me to add database connections?

Tags: google-app-maker

If I attempt to add a new SQL data model, a popup shows up explaining that the feature is locked and I must contact my administrator (myself). However, there is no further explanation found in the documentation on how to unlock this feature.

This is how AppMaker used to look back when it allowed me to add database connections:

[image]

This is how AppMaker looks now when starting a new app:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The App Maker engineers are doing crazy changes now and then. I believe their point of view is to make the platform better but this kind of things really annoys me and makes life harder, honestly.

I ran across this problem and find out that they are forcing admins to set up a default instance in the G Suite Admin console. You can read more about that **[here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7550053)**. You haven't completed that step and that is why you see what you are seeing. Although, it's crazy! What if I don't wanna do that?! But they are the product owners and they establish the rules so we have to suck it up and do what they want! Unless a bunch of people complain about it, they are not changing the behavior.

Fortunately, I was able to find a work around. So what we (you and me) are trying to do, is set up a custom sql database. Right now, that will only be available if you've already done what I described above. So the work around is to import an app that already has a custom sql database set up and then modify the Google Cloud SQL address. Look at the example below:

[image]

Here is the **[demo workaround app](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12eHU2iB2CPUKBKr1KKsGvgCsZU9HtAGK)** that I use. Download it to your machine, then import it as in the image above. I hope this helps!